# Basic Authentication not working on Apache 2.4.6 <Location ...>

Tags: apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

Just moved a site to new server, replaced the Allow.... directives with Require...

Centos7, Apache 2.4.6

I have one location that I was using basic authentication and working fine, here is the directive in httpd.conf

```
<Location "/solr">
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Secure Search"
 AuthBasicProvider file
 AuthUserFile /var/solr/htusers
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I no longer get the login dialog?  I'm using the same name/password file created with htpasswd.
The modules are loaded.

Setting LogLevel to debug I see the following in the error_log when opening https://URL/solr , indicating it is applying Require all granted to the location?

> [Sat Jun 27 13:29:09.183916 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 57060] mod_authz_core.c(809):[client 174.30.215.226:59976] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted

> [Sat Jun 27 13:29:09.183934 2020] [authz_core:debug] [pid 57060] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 174.30.215.226:59976] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

Comment: Check your configuration carefully and find the other `Require all granted` directive.

Comment: I had 2 <Location /solr> directives, the first in the httpd.conf with the auth stuff second was the reverseproxy. On my old server 2.2 the reversproxy.conf loaded first, in my new server it had the reverseproxy.conf loading second, I swapped them and all is well!  Thanks for clue...