# Apache 2.4 no auth config works in VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-auth

I'm setting up a brand new server — I literally just spun up an AWS EC2 instance, did a fresh install of apache and mod_ssl, and have close to the simplest of configs. Apache appears to ignore any auth configuration (including `LogLevel`) in `VirtualHost` blocks.

This is with Apache 2.4.51 on amzn2.x86_64 Linux.

I started by redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, and then followed the basic instructions for [Apache 2.4 Authentication and Authorization](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#introduction). That got me to the following virtual.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        LogLevel debug
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key
        <Directory "/var/www/html">
                AllowOverride All
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Restricted Files"
                # (Following line optional)
                AuthBasicProvider file
                AuthUserFile "/mount/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
                Require user someuser
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

In general, the above seems to be working, with the exception of auth stuff. If I go to my IP address in a web browser, it correctly redirects to 443, it serves the certificates from the specified (non-standard) path, and I can see it logging `debug` level activity, at least for mod_ssl. However, it just serves this index.html from `/var/www/html/` (**NB**: `/var/www/html` is a symlink).

I found [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1023173/basic-authentication-not-working-on-apache-2-4-6-location), which led me to look for any `Require all granted` directives.

```
# pwd
/etc/httpd/conf.d
# grep Require * 2>/dev/null
autoindex.conf:# Required modules: mod_authz_core, mod_authz_host,
autoindex.conf:    Require all granted
ssl.conf:#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
ssl.conf:#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
ssl.conf:#   o StrictRequire:
ssl.conf:#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
ssl.conf:#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
userdir.conf:    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
virtual.conf:       Require user someuser
welcome.conf:    Require all granted
```

The one in `autoindex.conf` is inside of a `<Directory "/usr/share/httpd/icons">` block, and the one in `welcome.conf` is in `<Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>`. I *did* find one in `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf`:

```
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Note, on this installation (via `yum` on Amazon Linux 2), the main config file is `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf`. The last line of that file is `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`. My main configuration I posted above is in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/virtual.conf`.

I tried commenting out that `Require all granted` and restarted the server, but no change. That's when I noticed that it doesn't appear to be doing anything at all. That previously mentioned question showed some entries in his log file. However, even
though I have `LogLevel debug`, I'm not seeing anything related to `authz_core` in the log files, as he was. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

At this point, I tried a number of modifications inside of the `<VirtualHost>` block:

- I tried wrapping the lines `AuthType basic` through `Require user someuser` in a `<RequireAll>` block
- I tried adding `Require all denied` before the `Require user`
- I tried using a `.htaccess` file with the same configuration
- I tried changing the `AllowOverride All` to `AllowOverride All AuthConfig` and using a `.htaccess` file
- I tried extending the logging to `LogLevel debug auth_basic:trace1 authz_core:trace1`

In all cases, no change, and the configuration parses fine. The server just serves the page, and there's nothing in any of the log files.

**However**, if I make changes in the main `conf/httpd.conf` file inside of the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` block, things work as expected:

- changing `Require all granted` to `Require all denied` (instead of commenting it out) blocks all access
- changing `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride AuthConfig` makes my `.htaccess` file with the same auth configuration as in the `<VirtualHost>` block work as expected — it solicits username and password
- turning up logging with `LogLevel debug auth_basic:trace1 authz_core:trace1` gets me lots of logging

So, to summarize, even though my `<VirtualHost>` config is working in general (redirect, SSL, debug for everything except auth), it appears to silently ignore any `auth` configuration, including `LogLevel`.

In the short term, I've solved my problem by undoing all the changes I made in the main config file, so things don't get overridden during a software update, and put them in `conf/00-override.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    # (Following line optional)
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/mount/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
    Require user someuser
</Directory>
```

However, it would be good to be able to configure authorization at the virtual-host level. Any ideas?

Comment: Have the necessary modules been loaded?   What do you get in the error log when you restart Apache?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure which are "necessary", but `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` _looks_ right to me. In the error log on restart, the only messages are about heartbeat monitor and mpm not being supported. I can put the full restart log in the question, if you think it will help.

Comment: There's no .conf file in /etc/httpd that specifies access rules for /var/www and an "allowoverride none" ?

Comment: /etc/httpd/httpd.conf does have a `Require all granted` for /var/www before its /var/www/html entry, but I assumed the later, more specific took precedence. In that same file /, /var/www, and /var/www/html all have an allowoverride none.

Comment: You are correct, "allowoverride" counts for .htaccess.  There's no .htaccess in /var/www/html?    You do have two configurations for /var/www/html.  I wonder in what order they are parsed.

Comment: Also, don't forget to clear your browser's cache.

Comment: The only thing in /var/www/html is an index.html that says Hello World. According to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging "Sections inside <VirtualHost> sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.", so should be fine. I can't imagine how caching would matter, since I see the request on the server, but I cleared it anyhow, and still same behavior.

Comment: Also, I tried adding `Require all denied` to the vhost config, and still same behavior.

Comment: Add separate logs for that host, to see if it is being used.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille — substantial edits to the question; it now seems clear it's a problem inside the virtual-host blocks.

Comment: It used to be the case (I was already working with Apache 1.4) that one had to activate the use of VirtualHosts, but I thought that was no longer the case.  Did you try separate logs for that host?  Any other VirtualHost configs apart from the two you show?